# How to display maximum value of colorbar in MATLAB plots as `>x`?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colorbar, colormap

I am plotting a spatial plot, where I am displaying values from say 0 to 20 in colormap.

This is what I am doing,

```
caxis([0 20])    
h = colorbar('Fontsize', 4, 'LineWidth', 0.15);
```

Below is the generated colorbar,

[image]

Since, few values are larger than 20, I want to display the largest tick value in colorbar as `>20` instead of `20`.

How to do it?

Comment: but I do not want to put any marker rather I want to make sure each time last value is shown with '>' symbol, I have seen such plots in MATLAB, there must be some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this after your code:

```
h.TickLabels{end} = '>20';
```

or more generally:

```
h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];
```

Comment: It works, but I encountered another issue with another subplot. For one subplot it showed `>8` but  for other plots the scale is repeating please see here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IJ96ucYslr0htvZIViwXbi8YjCV4Hc6w/view

How to resolve this.

Comment: It seems like in the right colorbar you change `h.Ticks` after you set `TickLabels`. Don't do that. First set the ticks and then change the last tick label.

Comment: I haven't changed any `h.Ticks`, For different subplots I am just using `h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];` 

When I use it for first subplot it works fine, but for second and third it create problem. Even if I use it for third subplot leaving first and second it also create problem. This is strange.

Comment: I just tried it with several subplots in the same figure and it works fine. Please try to create a [mcve] of the problem, and if you didn't solve the problem in this process (it often happens that defining the problem is 90% of the way for solving it) post another question with your [mcve].

Comment: Hey @EBH I have put my new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951188/error-in-matlab-colorbar-tick-labeling

Comment: @Mario great. you can see my answer there.