# Error in MATLAB colorbar tick labeling?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot, colorbar

I am plotting 9 subplots as shown in figure below with one color bar for three subplots.

Here I want to show the highest value in color bar as `> value`, surprisingly when I manually edit the tick label as `h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];` the color bar starts repeating the value.

When I remove `h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];` the color bar show no problem. When I change the figure size in `set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 8 8])` as `[0 0 5 5]` colorbar labeling again changes.

How to resolve this error?

Below are my working example and output image:

```
data = [1 2 3; 5 7 3; 12 29 14; 1 7 3; 2 8 3; 5 4 1; 2 2 1; 2 3 1; 1 5 2];
for i=1:9
    subplot(3, 3, i)
    plot(data(i,:));
    if ismember(i, [1:3])        
        caxis([0 20])
        if i==3
            h = colorbar('Fontsize', 6, 'LineWidth', 0.15, 'TickDirection', 'out',...
                         'TickLength', 0.02);
            set(h, 'Position', [.935 .6867 .01 .2533])
            h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];
        end
    end
    if ismember(i, [4:6])       
        caxis([0 6])
        if i==6
            h = colorbar('Fontsize', 6, 'LineWidth', 0.15, 'TickDirection', 'out',...
                         'TickLength', 0.02);
            set(h, 'Position', [.935 .3733 .01 .2533])
            h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];
        end
    end
    if ismember(i, [7:9])        
        caxis([0 4])
        if i==9
            h = colorbar('Fontsize',6, 'LineWidth', 0.15, 'TickDirection', 'out',...
                         'TickLength', 0.02);
            set(h, 'Position', [.936 .06 .01 .2533])
            h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];
        end
    end
end
set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 8 8])
print('test', '-djpeg', '-r300')
close all
```

[image]

Comment: You could add that answers of yours in comment, as it gave me idea that once TickLabels is manually changed things get messed up. Thanks.

Comment: @SardarUsama I read your edited answer, but here I posted a MCVE to illustrate my problem. In actual case I have average rainfall data, mean and variance, that ranges from 0 to 400; and color bar limits are being fixed at 95 percentile value. Since, I have many plots to make, it would be very difficult to edit ticklabel interval each time.

Comment: Nope, I am doing this `limit = prctile(datat, 95);
        caxis([0,limit])` each time.

Comment: Rainfall is different for Monsoon, post monsoon, and pre monsoon; and on a spatial scale where we have 4000+ grids max values for some grids go upto 400. In such case we don't know where the 95 percentile would come, and what if 95 percentile value is 45 for a particular month, in such case fixing interval manually will not give a  decent scale. Again the default intervals comes fine but setting them manually like 3 or 9 or 15 will make the colorbar look ugly.

Comment: Try adding a `drawnow` and `pause(0.1)` after drawing the color bar and before setting the Ticklabels property.

Comment: So do something like `set(h, 'Ticks', 0:limit/6:limit);` This will create 6 ticks

Comment: I did this but in this case ticks sometime goes into decimal, and we n never show interval like 7, 13, 19, 24, rather it should be like 5, 10, 15, or 10, 20, 30, ... this is how I am require to present.

Comment: I could do what I wanted by trying different paper sizes, but for another country I may have to do this trial and error again. See here how it should be to have some idea regarding scale https://drive.google.com/open?id=14K8i5VewnLBKFQ9OGaxSqGrZVr3TZ-MX

Comment: I do not want multiples of 5 and 10. I just trued to show you how the division should be, many time division of 5 and 10 won't work and the limit will be 12. If you see the plots you would find the difference in spread of values. I have to evaluate such 20+ plots, so something has to be automated yet meaningful. In this plot division are default Matlab values.

Answer (score 2):

**Why is this happening?**
Manually changing the `TickLabels` changes the `TickLabelsMode` property to manual and the control gets lost for zooming/panning/resizing the figure window.

---

**How can this be fixed?**

- Use a listener that will adjust the ticks itself. It may require undocumented features. You can take ideas on implementing a listener for `colorbar` from Yair Altman's [***this utility***](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat-set-a-dynamic-format-of-axes-tick-labels). This is for ticklabels of axes and would require some tweaking to work for `colorbar`.

***or a relatively simpler approach would be to:***

- Change the `'TicksMode'` to manual i.e.:
  Before this line `h.TickLabels{end} = ['>' h.TickLabels{end}];`, include
  this line:

  ```
  set(h, 'Ticks', get(h,'Ticks'));  %or h.Ticks = h.Ticks; for >= R2014b
  ```

  This ensures that the ticks remain the same and hence the number of ticks also remains the same and therefore ticklabels will not malfunction on zooming/panning/resizing the figure window.

  If you want to have more or less ticks than you originally get then set them as:

  ```
  %Adjust the increment as desired. I set it as 1 (default)
  set(h, 'Ticks', in1:1:in2);       %or h.Ticks = in1:1:in2; for >= R2014b
  %where in1 and in2 are the 1st and 2nd input args you used for caxis respectively
  ```

***or if you're only concerned with the output jpeg file*** and your ticklabels are malfunctioned in the output image file then:

- Set the `PaperUnits` / `PaperPosition` at the beginning of the plotting instead of doing that at the end. This will not automate the ticklabels but will only make the temporary adjustment.

Comment: I kept set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 8 8])` in the beginning of the code, but it doesn't help. Colorbar issue remained the same.

Comment: Is your concern using the image in MATLAB? or you're concerned with the output jpeg image file? Did you change the figure size after running the code again? I think you did. If you didn't, you wouldn't have that problem in the output jpeg file

Comment: Do you get the wrong output in the output jpeg file?

Comment: @SardarUsama I wan't final output file in jpeg format. The figure window doesn't show any issue with my code as well, but upon zooming it the color bar gets messed up.

Comment: `Manually changing the TickLabels changes the TickLabelsMode property to manual and the control is lost for zooming and panning.` Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Mario You need to add a listener as I already mentioned in my answer

Comment: @sardarUsama I don't know what listener is? Can you edit my code with Listener, so that I can understand.

Comment: @shamalaia I hope it fixes now

Answer (score 2):

As [Sardar wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951716/2627163), the only option to solve this automatically, and not lose the auto-scaling of the ticks when the figure window size is changed is to add a listener. This is how to do it:

Copy the following function to an m-file, and save it in the folder you work on this figure (i.e. your current path):

```
function set_cb_lables
% add '>' to the last tick label in all colorbars

h = findobj(gcf,'Type','Colorbar'); % get all colorbars handels
set(h,{'TickLabelsMode'},{'auto'}); % change thier mode to 'auto'
tiklbl = get(h,{'TickLabels'}); % get all tick labels after the change
for k = 1:numel(tiklbl) 
    tiklbl{k}{end} = ['>' tiklbl{k}{end}]; % add '>' to the last tick
end
set(h,{'TickLabels'},tiklbl); % replace the current ticklabels with tiklbl
end
```

Then, in your code, add this line after the loop:

```
set(gcf,'SizeChangedFcn','set_cb_lables'); % aplly the function 'set_cb_lables' upon any size change
```

This will add '>' automatically to the last tick label upon any resizing of the figure.

This solution is better than just getting the ticks before adding the '>' because now if the window gets bigger, the colorbar is populated automatically with more ticks.

Comment: I did exactly what you suggested, saved the function file in same directory, and added `set(gcf,'SizeChangedFcn','set_cb_lables');` after the loop i.e., before `set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'inches', 'PaperPosition', [0 0 8 8])`. This fixes the 2nd and third scale but the first scale shows the same issue.

Comment: @Mario, Just to be sure - you use the same script as in your question, right? (one figure for all subplots). Tey to remove the `;` at the end of the first line in the function `set_cb_lables`, so you'll see the size of `h` after resizing.

Comment: Here is the script, function, and output image https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HgXRZfz2rmEYqnEX3rdsx3v7PvvXoGAY First colorbar is incorrect

Comment: Weird... When I use your files I get the correct result. I'm using version 2017a, so that might be a bug that was fixed, otherwise, it may be some default settings that are changed in your Matlab. As the last shot, I would try to reset Matlab (and even the PC) and see if it helps (if you haven't done that aleady). If not, you may have access (depends on your license) to [Matlab online](https://matlab.mathworks.com/) where you can run your code on the last version of Matlab

Comment: I am using MATLAB 2016a